# How to get a CSS Variable defined in `:root` selector inside a nested React functional component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

## Motivation

My goal is to have CSS be my one source of truth for colors. I could make a copy of these values into JavaScript variables, but if I wanted to change a shade of red, then I'd have to update code in two separate places.

I have a CSS file that holds a long list of colors, stored as CSS Variables (a.k.a. CSS Property Values).

```css
/* variables.css */
:root {
    --indicator---red: rgba(255, 46, 46, 1);
    --indicator---red--dark: rgba(201, 37, 37, 1);
    --indicator---green: rgba(71, 205, 38, 1);
    --indicator---green--dark: rgba(57, 172, 28, 1);
    --indicator---amber: rgba(244, 182, 60, 1);
    --indicator---amber--dark: rgba(208, 156, 56, 1);
}
```

I'm using React. I have a functional component called `TrafficLight` that needs to consume the colors directly from my CSS Variables. I wish to do the following:

```js
// TrafficLight.js
function TrafficLight({status}) {
  switch (status) {
    case "GREEN":
     color = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue("--indicator-green")
     break;
    case "YELLOW":
     color = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue("--indicator-amber")
     break;
    case "RED":
     color = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue("--indicator-red");
     break;
  }
  return (<div className="circle" style={{backgroundColor: color}} />);
}
```

## Problem

The problem I'm facing is that React cannot access the CSS Variables defined in `:root`, because `CSSStyleDeclaration.getPropertyValue()` always returns an empty string.

## What I've tried

1. Using vanilla JavaScript to access the DOM, but React uses a virtual DOM. So, this method can't "see" the `:root` selector:

- `getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--my-var')`
- `getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--my-var')`
- `window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--my-var')`

2. Waiting for the component to mount and perform the lookups within a `useEffect()` block.
3. I'd like to avoid using `useRef` and prop-drilling the `:root` reference all the way down to my component, since my project has a structure like this:

```
<App>
  <Parent1>
    <Parent2>
      <Parent3>
         ... // Several components deep
           <TrafficLight>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the CSS Variables without checking for the computed style. Create a function within your `TrafficLight` component to get the color based on the `status` property and just assign the color directly to the `backgroundColor` property

```
// TrafficLight.js

function TrafficLight({status}) {
  
  const getColor = () => {
    switch(status) {
      case "GREEN": {
        return "--indicator-green"
      }
      case "GREEN": {
        return "--indicator-amber"
      }
      case "GREEN": {
        return "--indicator-red"
      }
      default: 
        return "--YOUR-DEFAULT-COLOR-IF-THE-OTHERS-DONT-MATCH"
    }
  }

  // use the var CSS function to access the property
  const myColor = `var(--${getColor()})`; 

  return (<div className="circle" style={{backgroundColor: myColor}} />);
}
```